# Shortcode based chart plugin

Tags: plugins, shortcode

Does anyone know of a WP plugin that can generate charts based on shortcode parameters?

i.e. something like this `[chart type="bar" values="1,2,4,7,3"]`, `[chart type="pie" values="43,32,38"]` so there is no need to upload .txt/.csv files, use Google Sheets, etc.

Thanks!

PS: We need to be shortcode based because of the way our site works (a database generates some of the content).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a customized plugin to realize this. What chart engine will you use? You probably have to create a new function in `function.php`. I recently realized a Google chart plugin to show data in a graph. Maybe this topic will help you: [Dynamic data in `wp_register_script` needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302704/dynamic-data-in-wp-register-script-needed)

Comment: Agree. I have tried looking more since asking here and I haven't found any plugin that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of plugins I found for a similar purpose several years ago. You can see it any still work. There are likely more now.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rj-quickcharts

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-chart-builder

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-charts

https://wordpress.org/plugins/protovis-loader

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-visualize-for-wordpress

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tally-graph

https://wordpress.org/plugins/fotherplot

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-chart-shortcode

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-chart-generator

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-graph

Comment: Thanks, but I also found these plugins myself. What I need is one that accepts shortcodes instead of .txt/.csv files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find one?

It seems such a trivial thing... a shortcode to create a pie chart on the fly.

The best I've found is TP Piebuilder, but I wasn't overly keen on the look and feel. I just need a simple pie chart :/

http://www.petreview.co.uk/dog/dry-food/naturediet/